# Tensorflow: Convert Tensor to numpy array then pass into a feed_dict

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, mnist, softmax

I'm trying to build a softmax regression model for CIFAR classification. At first when I tried to pass in my images and labels into the feed dictionary, I got an error that said that feed dictionaries do not accept Tensors. I then converted them into numpy arrays using .eval() but the program hangs at the .eval() line and does not continue any further. How can I pass this data into the feed_dict?

## CIFARIMAGELOADING.PY

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 as cf


IMAGE_SIZE = 24
BATCH_SIZE = 128


def loadimagesandlabels(size):
    # Load the images from the CIFAR data directory
    FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
    data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i) for i in xrange(1, 6)]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    read_input = cf.cifar10_input.read_cifar10(filename_queue)

    # Reshape and crop the image
    height = IMAGE_SIZE
    width = IMAGE_SIZE
    reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
    cropped_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, 3])

    # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples
    print('Filling queue with CIFAR images')
    num_preprocess_threads = 16
    min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
    min_queue_examples = int(BATCH_SIZE*min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)

    images, label_batch = tf.train.batch([cropped_image,read_input.label],batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_threads=num_preprocess_threads, capacity=min_queue_examples+3*BATCH_SIZE)
    print(images)
    print(label_batch)
    return images, tf.reshape(label_batch, [BATCH_SIZE])
```

## CIFAR.PY

```
#Set up placeholder vectors for image and labels
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 1728])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,10])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1728,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))


#Implement regression model. Multiply input images x by weight matrix W, add the bias b
#Compute the softmax probabilities that are assigned to each class
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

#Define cross entropy
#tf.reduce sum sums across all classes and tf.reduce_mean takes the average over these sums
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y), reduction_indices = [1]))

#Train the model
#Each training iteration we load 128 training examples. We then run the train_step operation
#using feed_dict to replace the placeholder tensors x and y_ with the training examples
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

#Open up a Session
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
for i in range(1000) :
    images, labels = CIFARImageLoading.loadimagesandlabels(size=BATCH_SIZE)
    unrolled_images = tf.reshape(images, (1728, BATCH_SIZE))

    #convert labels to their one_hot representations
    # should produce [[1,0,0,...],[0,1,0...],...]
    one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices= labels, depth=NUM_CLASSES, on_value=1.0, off_value= 0.0, axis=-1)

    print(unrolled_images)
    print(one_hot_labels)
    images_numpy, labels_numpy = unrolled_images.eval(session=sess), one_hot_labels.eval(session=sess)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {x: images_numpy, y_:labels_numpy})




#Evaluate the model
#.equal returns a tensor of booleans, we want to cast these as floats and then take their mean
#to get percent correctness (accuracy)
print("evaluating")
test_images, test_labels = CIFARImageLoading.loadimagesandlabels(TEST_SIZE)
test_images_unrolled = tf.reshape(test_images, (1728, TEST_SIZE))
test_images_one_hot = tf.one_hot(indices= test_labels, depth=NUM_CLASSES, on_value=1.0, off_value= 0.0, axis=-1)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x: unrolled_images.eval(), y_ : test_images_one_hot.eval()}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres a couple of things that you not are understanding really well. Throughout your graph you will work with Tensors. You define Tensors by either using `tf.placeholder` and feeding them in the `session.run(feed_dict{})` or with `tf.Variable` and initializing it with `session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())`. You must feed your input this way, and it should be numpy arrays in the same as shape as you expect in the placeholders. Here's a simple example:

```
images = tf.placeholder(type, [1728, BATCH_SIZE])
labels = tf.placeholder(type, [size])

'''
    Build your network here so you have the variable: Output
'''

images_feed, labels_feed = CIFARImageLoading.loadimagesandlabels(size=BATCH_SIZE)
# here you can see your output
print sess.run(Output, feed_dict = {x: images_feed, y_:labels_feed})
```

You do not feed tf.functions with numpy arrays, you always feed them with Tensors. And the `feed_dict` is always fed with numpy arrays. The thing is: you will never have to convert tensors to numpy arrays for the input, that does not make sense. Your input must be numpy arrays, if it's a list, you can use `np.asarray(list)`, if it's a tensor, you are doing this wrong.

I do not know what `CIFARImageLoading.loadimagesandlabels` returns to you, but I imagine it's not a Tensor, it's probably a numpy array already, so just get rid of this `.eval()`.

Comment: thanks michel, I edited the post to show how I built the model. Are you saying that my placeholder sizes are incorrect?

Comment: So the thing is: Tensor.eval() == session.run(Tensor). So you cannot really call tensor.eval() just like that. Try:

images_numpy, labels_numpy = session.run(unrolled_images, arguments), session.run(one_hot_labels, arguments)

Comment: And yes, the numpy array you feed must have the same shape as your placeholder, make sure that`s the case.

Comment: do i need to supply arguments? and if so, what arguments do i need to specify? because when i don't, the code still hangs.

Comment: the first argument of session.run is a Tensor. the second argument is usually feed_dict with all the initializations. I will just edit my answer to show you better.

Comment: Just included CIFARImageLoading.py and i'm getting a tensor from it